# Dual basis explicit form

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

I'm reading FIS Linear Algebra chapter 2.6, Example 4. Usually when defining a function using direct delta, for example $f(i,j)=\delta_{ij}$ doesn't need anything more.

But why do we need to solve system of equation to find dual basis for a given basis of the vector space? Why does this give a so-called 'explicit form', but not directly from just the dirac-delta definition?

Another question, say by solving the linear system of equations, we obtain $f_1(e_1)=-1$, $f_1(e_2)=-3$, why is it immediate that $f_1(x,y)=-x+3y$?

Comment: You might want to make your question more self-contained. It will take effort but it will help you get an answer. In particular there are at least 4 editions of Friedberg,Insel,Spence's Linear Algebra according to my amazon search, and the examples between editions of a textbook are known to change.

Comment: This is more like a general approach. I'm using 4th edition, but I'm sure every linear algebra textbook in their chapter about dual basis would have an example like this.

Comment: I know that this is a question about the method rather than the particular example. But I find it hard to understand what you are saying without the example.

Comment: In the context $f_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$ isn’t a function definition. It’s telling you the value of $f_i$ for a specific argument.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "FIS" is and can't help you with your first question, sorry.

Regarding the second one: $(x,y) = xe_1+ye_2$, so $f(x,y) = f(xe_1+ye_2) = xf(e_1)+yf(e_2)= x(-1)+y(-3) = -x-3y$ (I assume you have a typo in your question). Happy 2018!

Comment: Happy New Year! FIS stands for the author Stephen H. Friedberg, Arnold J. Insel ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are talking about the following:

> $\{e_1,e_2\} $ is a basis of a 2-dimensional space $X$ ; find the corresponding dual basis $\{ f_1,f_2 \}$.

I have never heard of an 'explicit form' for a dual/basis. I presume you mean computing/finding it.

The dirac delta $\delta_{ij}$ is (usually) defined on pairs of integers $i,j$. By itself, it has nothing to do with bases or vector spaces. The dual basis is defined relative to a chosen basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ of your original vector space $X$ as
$$ f_i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}, \quad i,j=1,2$$
which can be understood as a matrix equation, or a system of 4 equations, once one chooses to write things in coordinates.

This equation 
uniquely determines the linear maps $f_i$. The point of this example (i presume) is for you to figure out what linear maps they are. I don't know how much more 'direct from the dirac-delta definition' you can have than the above equation.

You may know that the dual bases are linear maps. Hence this can be done because linear maps are completely determined by their action on a basis, purely from the linearity (max_zorn's answer).

Perhaps what confuses you is that the 'explicit form' of $f_i$ depends not only on the choice of $e_i$, but also the basis you choose to express them in. That is, $f_i$ is a linear map on $X$. Suppose $e'_1,e'_2$ is a different basis of $X$. Then we can write $f_i$ in this basis too; we will get different numbers out.

Comment: But does it only make sense as a matrix equation? Why $\delta_{ij}$ itself wouldn't stand?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'won't stand'? It is literally 4 linear equations and that's all a matrix equation is

Comment: @ZHU I feel like if we had an example it would be easier to explain...

Comment: *Kronecker* delta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla whoops, I'll fix this if OP gives me reason to make an edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’ve misinterpreted the expression $f_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$ in the definition of dual basis. Take a closer look at the differences between this expression and the function definition $F(i,j)=\delta_{i,j}$ (I’ve replaced $f$ with $F$ for clarity). The arguments to $F$ are a pair of numbers and the expression says that for any inputs, the output of $F$ is identical to that of the Kronecker delta function. Typically, that’s used with natural numbers, so $F: \mathbb N\times\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$.

On the other hand, if our vector space is $V[K]$ then $f_i:V\to K$. The function takes an element of $V$—a vector—as input and outputs a scalar. It can’t in general be equal to the Kronecker delta *function* and so the expression $f_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$ isn’t in and of itself a function definition. What it does do is tell you the value of $f_i$ for a particular set of inputs, namely the elements of a basis for $V$. The indices in this expression aren’t inputs the to function as they are in the definition of $F$. Instead, they’re part of the names of the objects in the equation. Using indices and the Kronecker delta in this expression allows the $(\dim V)^2$ constraints $$f_1(e_1)=1 \\f_1(e_2)=0\\f_3(e_3)=0 \\ \vdots \\f_2(e_1)=0 \\ f_2(e_2)=1 \\ f_2(e_3)=0 \\ \vdots \\ f_3(e_1)=0 \\ f_3(e_2) = 0 \\ f_3(e_3) = 1 \\ \vdots$$ on the elements of a dual basis to be expressed very compactly. Now, since these are linear operators on $V$, knowing their values on the basis vectors is enough to determine their values on any elements of $V$, so in that sense these are function definitions, but of a very different flavor from $F(i,j)=\delta_{ij}$.